# cannot find file /dev/vmnet0

Tags: 12.04, vmware, interface

I am working on ubuntu lts 12.04 server on VMware Workstation environment. I need to add permissions to the file `vmnet0` corresponding to the virtual interface. But I can't find it in the `/dev` directory. (I have already installed vmware-tools)
How can i add the corresponding file?